# Checking an MD5 of a device

Tags: c#, cryptography

The point of this code snippet is to **calculate and compare an MD5** obtained from a USB device connected to the computer against a database to check its validity.

```
var md5String = string.Empty;
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    var md5CRC = md5.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(destinationFilename));
    foreach (byte b in md5CRC)
        md5String += b.ToString("X2");
}

// here I check the MD5 against the database to check the usb device is valid
```

The code meets its purpose, but I want to know how I can improve this code.

Comment: You only posted the MD5 code but omitted the CRC code.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I only posted the code regarding the MD5, because the engineer stated later that only the MD5 should be checked, it was a confusion on my part.

Comment: [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa) lists *many* different ways to convert bytes to hex. Personally I like `BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-","")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using string concatenation in a loop is a no go because each time you do a `+=` a new string object will be created because strings are immutable.

To use the right tool for the job I would suggest to use a `StringBuilder` instead. Using a `StringBuilder` doesn't have this restriction because the passed strings are just appended char by char to the internal buffer.

Using braces `{}` although they might be optional will make your code less error prone.

By extracting the building of the hex string representation to a separate method the responsibility is split nicely and could be reused if needed. Having this as a extension method could serve well.

```
private string ToHex(this byte[] values)
{
    if (values == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(values.Length * 2);
    foreach (var b in values)
    {
        sb.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

resulting in the former code like this

```
var md5String = string.Empty;
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    var md5CRC = md5.ComputeHash(File.ReadAllBytes(destinationFilename));

    md5String = md5CRC.ToHex();
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot to use stringBuilder even though I've used it in the past, I guess coding in a hurry has its problems, marked as answer

Answer (score 4):

`ReadAllBytes` loads the whole file into memory. That's prohibitive for large files and puts a lot of pressure on the GC even for moderate file sizes. I recommend hashing a stream instead.

```
byte[] HashFile(string filename, Func<HashAlgorithm> createHash)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    using (var hasher = createHash())
    {
        return hasher.ComputeHash(stream);
    }
}

string ToHexString(byte[] bytes)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", "");
}
```

Combining it with a `ToHexString` method, like @Heslacher recommended:

```
ToHexString(HashFile(filename, MD5.Create))
```

Answer (score 3):

Helsacher (as usual) has provided an excellent answer but I'd like to suggest an alternative implementation to his extension method:

```
public static string ToHexString(this IEnumerable<Byte> bytes)
{
    if (bytes == null) 
    {
        // throw or possible return null if you're in to that sort of thing.
    }
    return string.Join(string.Empty, bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
}
```

It operates on an `IEnumerable<Byte>` not just an array which makes it more generally usable. I also think using string.Join is more readable than a foreach loop but your mileage may vary.

Comment: This answer is quite brilliant too, I'll keep it on my library and use it depending on my needs, thanks as well for the help

Comment: It seems you don't like returning null values, can you explain me why?

Comment: @OscarGuillamon - It depends entirely on the situation - if `null` byte arrays are allowed in your code I think you should return `null` if not, I think you should throw an exception. If it were my own code, I would throw an `ArgumentNullException` as I would use an empty byte array to mean no data not null.

Comment: It makes sense you point of view, I'll keep it in mind when developing future code, thanks for the tip

Comment: In general I agree with the throwing when receiving `null` arguments, but with `ToHexString` it can be convenient to return `null` so you can visualize `byte[]` values without caring if they're `null`.